# Problem using UART0 in TM4C123 Tiva C Launch Pad

Tags: embedded, uart, arm, texas-instruments, tm4c123g

I'm trying to interface UART0 with the my laptop using the ICDI
the code I used is from Mazidi's book :

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "tm4c123gh6pm.h"
void UART0Tx(char c);
void delayMs(int n);
int main(void)
{
    SYSCTL->RCGCUART |= 1; /* provide clock to UART0 */
    SYSCTL->RCGCGPIO |= 1; /* enable clock to PORTA */
    delayMs(20); /* wait for output line to stabilize */
    /* UART0 initialization */  
    UART0->CTL = 0; /* disable UART0 */
    UART0->IBRD =  104; /* 16MHz/16=1MHz, 1MHz/104=9600 baud rate */
    UART0->FBRD =  11; /* fraction part, see Example 4-4 */
    UART0->CC = 0; /* use system clock */
    UART0->LCRH = 0x60; /* 8-bit, no parity, 1-stop bit, no FIFO */
    UART0->CTL = 0x301; /* enable UART0, TXE, RXE */
    /* UART0 TX0 and RX0 use PA0 and PA1. Set them up. */
    GPIOA->DEN = 0x03; /* Make PA0 and PA1 as digital */
    GPIOA->AFSEL = 0x03; /* Use PA0,PA1 alternate function */
    GPIOA->PCTL = 0x11; /* configure PA0 and PA1 for UART */
    delayMs(1); /* wait for output line to stabilize */
    for(;;)
    {
        UART0Tx('M');
        delayMs(1000) ; 

    }
}
/* UART0 Transmit */
/* This function waits until the transmit buffer is available then */
/* writes the character in the transmit buffer. It does not wait */
/* for transmission to complete. */
void UART0Tx(char c)
{
    while((UART0->FR & 0x20) != 0); /* wait until Tx buffer not full */
    UART0->DR = c; /* before giving it another byte */
}
void delayMs(int n)
{
    int i = 0 , j = 0 ; 
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < 3180 ; j++)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

and there are no problems with the COM port I've set it up in a correct way and I made sure to modify options for target to get 16Mhz clock frequency and to debug using ICDI ( I'm using keil uvision IDE)

and All I get is this symbol

What should I do ?
[image]

Comment: Not related to your problem, but your `delayMs` is completely broken and will get optimized away by any half-decent compiler. The loop iterators must be `volatile`.

Comment: Anyway, start by verifying the baudrate with your scope. If you get strange symbols instead of the expected one, that's very likely the cause. Another classic mistake is missing signal ground.

Comment: I have changed the baud rate in the virtual terminal installed on my pc to 28800 and the baud rate in the code is still 9600 and the character was transmitted correctly 
what does that mean ?

Comment: What do you mean? If you have different baudrates on sender and receiver side, then that's obviously the problem. You have wrong baudrate divisors in the MCU code perhaps?

Comment: The baud rate in this code is 9600 and I got the divisor using the data sheet and the reference book 
When the baud rate in the pc terminal was 9600 the transmitted character was not the desired 
When I changed it in the pc terminal to 28800 and in my code it is still 9600 
it worked

Comment: The way I used for getting the integer part and the floating point part is based on the data sheet and a coding book for Mazidi 
Could it be some sort of type casting problem entring 104 and 11 values in a 32 bit register ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a3IQgz6

Comment: Yeah so your MCU apparently picked a baudrate which is 3 times too fast. Do you actually run the system clock at 16MHz then? Or is it in fact running at 48MHz?

Comment: 16 Mhz 
isn't it configured form here ? 

https://imgur.com/57HxfvL

Comment: I don't know your target but you typically have to write to some clock registers to pick clock source. And in case of external quartz, it all depends on what crystal you have mounted on the board.

Comment: No, that Xtal parameter in Options for Target does not set the MCU clock frequency.  The Xtal parameter is used to configure the Keil debugger and flash programmer utility running on your PC.

Comment: @ kkrambo
How Do I change it to 16 Mhz then ? I searched for registers like RCC and RCC2 but i'm a beginner and I don't know how to configure them

Comment: Download the [example software for the eval board](https://www.ti.com/tool/SW-EK-TM4C123GXL) from the [manufacturer's webpage](https://www.ti.com/tool/EK-TM4C123GXL).  It likely includes an example of how to set the MCU clock rate along with many other examples.

Comment: Try using a simple terminal emulator like teraterm